# Installing OpenCV on the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with the Raspbian OS

Tags: python, linux, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

We are trying to "make" OpenCV work on the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. We are using this tutorial: [Installing OpenCV on a Raspberry Pi](http://robertcastle.com/2014/02/installing-opencv-on-a-raspberry-pi/)

Unfortunately, the process pauses at 30%.

```
make
```

There is no error message. The tutorial says, that it takes about 10 hours to "make" it. We could not start the installing process yet.

```
sudo make install
```

- How is it possible, that it takes that long?
- Is there an "already compiled version" of OpenCV for the Raspberry Pi 2 Model B with the Raspbian operating system?

Comment: Have you tried `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv` or do you want to actually build it? Another option is a cross compilation toolchain and build it on your pc.

Comment: make takes about 2.5 hours to complete the build process- I did it using the exact same model just few days back. Stopping could be due to memory being full- check your filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the command suggested by Paul Rooney worked for me on a Raspberry Pi Model B and Raspbian OS.

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10207524)

Comment: Should I delete it? I was trying to answer the part of the question where he says "Is there an already compiled version..." but I don't seem to have worded it right :/

Answer (score 0):

try cmake command : 
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON  -D WITH_FFMPEG=OFF -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..

I believe the FFMEG is causing the trouble for you, so keep this option OFF, no it doesn't take 10 hours but it took around 2-3 hours on my raspberry pi. Raspbian Jessie is much stable, I would suggest you try it.